DB Error: constraint violation on changing case status
I am using three different case types on two of which I am getting a DB contraint violation when changing the case status. The failing SQL-query is the following:
INSERT INTO `civicrm_activity_contact` (`activity_id` , `contact_id` , `record_type_id` ) VALUES ( 6204 ,  0 ,  3 )  [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`drupal`.`civicrm_activity_contact`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_activity_contact_contact_id` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)]

The contact_id of 0 looks somewhat suspicious to me. Any ideas what's going wrong here?
I am on 5.72.2.
Stacktrace:
[debug] $backTrace = #0 /opt/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Error.php(443): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /opt/drupal/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(Civi\Core\Exception\DBQueryException))
#2 /opt/drupal/web/modules/contrib/civicrm/src/Civicrm.php(88): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#3 /opt/drupal/web/modules/contrib/civicrm/src/Controller/CivicrmController.php(83): Drupal\civicrm\Civicrm->invoke((Array:3))
#4 [internal function](): Drupal\civicrm\Controller\CivicrmController->main((Array:3), "")
#5 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(123): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:2))
#6 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(627): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
#7 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(124): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object(Drupal\Core\Render\RenderContext), Object(Closure))
#8 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(97): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext((Array:2), (Array:2))
#9 /opt/drupal/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(181): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
#10 /opt/drupal/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(76): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1)
#11 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(58): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, TRUE)
#12 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(48): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, TRUE)
#13 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ContentLength.php(28): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, TRUE)
#14 /opt/drupal/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(106): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ContentLength->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, TRUE)
#15 /opt/drupal/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(85): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, TRUE)
#16 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(48): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, TRUE)
#17 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(51): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, TRUE)
#18 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/AjaxPageState.php(36): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, TRUE)
#19 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/StackedHttpKernel.php(51): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\AjaxPageState->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, TRUE)
#20 /opt/drupal/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(704): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, TRUE)
#21 /opt/drupal/web/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#22 {main}


It looks like it can't figure out the case client. Is there anything unusual about the client? e.g are they in trash (soft deleted)?

It doesn't seem to depend on the case client but on the case type. The same client on a different case type works fine.

Do you have a stack trace? From ConfigAndLog.

I added the backtrace above. There ist also a verbose log entry [error]
$Fatal Error Details. Let me know if that's helpful.

Unfortunately that stack trace only says "something happened during the page run". I'd be looking for a stack trace that shows what file and what line number is generating the INSERT, and the list of which function(s) called it. Is that in the Fatal Error Details?

Find the full log entry here: https://ctxt.io/2/AAAoJgtKEw

It looks normal (except of course the error). It still seems like it's not able to determine the case client, like something is going wrong here.

Thank you! See the result below.

It turned out that the client ID in the case view is missing. That's because the case view is opened from SearchKit table which has a linked column "Case-ID". That link URL is generated by the SearchKit Table without the parameter cid. I have another table - which was probably build from a different SearchKit version (the UI is different) - that generates the link correctly.
SearchKit table link configuration with cid parameter:

SearchKit table link configuration without cid parameter:

Not sure how to proceed with this. Open another question?

probably best too and tag it as searchkit or jump over to https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/search-improvements

Thanks for writing this up. Had the same issue.

Oh, i solved it with the following custom output civicrm/contact/view/case?action=view&reset=1&id=[id]&cid=[Case_CaseContact_Contact_01.id] in the search kit configs.
